# PHP DOM and HTML entities

Tags: php, xml, dom, html-entities

I'm programming php cms with xml templates parsed by DOM and encountered error with html entities being replaced with symbols. Here is an example:

```
<CMS_STRING type="link" name="home" title="{enUS:&quot;Home Link&quot;}" />
```

After saving document (`$doc->saveXML()`) this gets converted to:

```
<CMS_STRING type="link" name="home" title="{enUS:"Home Link"}" />
```

And it causes errors with further template processing as I need to load and save multiple times (caching).

I also tried hex entities and `$doc->substituteEntities = false` but they were still converted.

EDIT: The problem actually was with `DOMNode::attributes->getNamedItem()->nodeValue` which I used to process attributes. It returns code with replaced html entities.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this](http://viper-7.com/bec87k) - When I print out the XML snippet, the `title` value is still properly encoded.

Comment: Check the user contributed notes on http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php, there are quite a few people having troubles with encoding...

Comment: Check substituteEntities property of DOMDocument: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.substituteentities

Comment: Please provide your fix/solution as an answer and accept it so that this question is marked "complete". That would be perfectly fine and good practice btw (instead of leaving the solution in the question).